# Derivatives using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$F(x) = 16.5x^2$

$x(Y) = 0.065Y + 0.68$

find $dF/dY$

derivative of $F(x) = 31x$,
derivative of $x(Y) = 0.065$

I don't understand how to find $dF/dY$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dF}{dY} = \dfrac{dF}{dx}\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dY} = 31x\cdot 0.065 = ...$